# how to find basis of rowspace from only row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I read somewhere that find the basis of a row space using only row vectors from the matrix
can anyone give an example? i don't really understand how you can find the basis from the row vectors

Comment: Do you know what a basis is? You shouldn't have trouble once you review the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Given a matrix $A$, its row space $R(A)$ is defined to be the span of its rows. So, the rows form a spanning set. You have found a basis of $R(A)$ if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent. However if not, you will have to drop off the rows that are linearly dependent on the "earlier" ones.  Doing so, you'll be left with linearly independent vectors that span $R(A)$, i.e. a  basis for $R(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

In linear algebra, there is a lot of symmetry between concepts related to the column spaces and row spaces.  The following matrix is an example:

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The column space has basis:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the row space has basis:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$.

These can be read directly off the columns of the matrix A (for the column space) and the rows of the matrix A (for the row space).

I hope this helps.

Comment: dont you have to find REF of the matrix and figure out which one is linear independent to figure out which vectors are rowspaces?

Comment: could you give an example of a more complex matrix?